# NativeScript adding xml namespace on Page tag

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm new to NativeScript. I have created a new project using the Angular Blank template. The navigation is done using page-router-outlet. I want to include a xmlns attribute on the page level. As far as i can see and understand the entire code is rendered inside a global page attribute. I've seen that I can modify the page properties by injecting the Page in a component and changing it's properties, but how can I do this for xmlns?

Best regards,
Vlad

Comment: When using **Angular** you are creating **HTML** pages and not XML (as it would be in NativeScript Core project). Why do you need to add XML namespace to an HTML page?

Comment: I want to add the nativescript-stripe plugin(https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-stripe) and in the instructions it says to include xmlns code on the page tag

Comment: The `xmlns` is used only in nativeScript Code with XML pages. To use the plugin in Angular, you need the Angular instructions (which are kind of missing in the README). Basically, do this https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-stripe/blob/master/angular/index.ts#L1-L2 in your module file and then directly use it in your HTML with tag `<CreditCardView></CreditCardView>`  (fo course add the params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register a UI component in Angular based application you should use `registerElement` and not XML namespaces (which is a concept used in NativeScript Core). Nowadays most plugin authors are doing this job for you, but still, some of the plugins are not migrated to use the latest techniques so in some cases, we should manually register the UI element.

I've created [this test applicaiton](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/tree/master/stackoverflow/stripeTest) which demonstrates how to use nativescript-stripe in Angular. Here are the steps to enable and use the plugin.

**Installation**

```
npm i nativescript-stripe --save
```

**Register the UI element** in `app.module.ts` as done [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/blob/master/stackoverflow/stripeTest/app/app.module.ts#L8-L9)

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("CreditCardView", () => require("nativescript-stripe").CreditCardView);
```

**Add [the following](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/blob/master/stackoverflow/stripeTest/app/main.ts#L6-L14) in `main.ts`** as required in the plugin README

```
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import * as platform from "tns-core-modules/platform";

declare const STPPaymentConfiguration;
app.on(app.launchEvent, (args) => {
    if (platform.isIOS) {
        STPPaymentConfiguration.sharedConfiguration().publishableKey = "yourApiKey";
    }
});
```

**Use the plugin in your HTML** ([example](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/blob/master/stackoverflow/stripeTest/app/item/items.component.html#L7))

```
<CreditCardView id="card"></CreditCardView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.  About the part about the plugin being supported only on iOS,  are you saying that the plugin cannot be used on Android? As far as i can see, nowhere in the project's Readme is written that, and there are parts where is written about using it on Android.

Comment: You are absolutely right - I've must have mistaken the README. Removed my statement